# LINQ to Entity does not support DbGeography conditions

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, geospatial, spatial-query

I'm using .NET 4.5 and EF 6.0 (also tried with 6.1.3).
I have Location *geography* column in an Entities table (*System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DbGeography*).

```
using System.Data.Spatial; //also tried Entity one

public class Entity
{
    public DbGeography Location {get;set;}
}
```

In LINQ I'm trying to select all entities which are inside a specified area.

```
var center = DbGeography.FromText(string.Format("POINT({0} {1})", latitude, longitude), 4326);
var region = center.Buffer(radius);
var result = db.Entities.Where(x => SqlSpatialFunctions.Filter(x.Location, region) == true).ToArray();
```

And this query returns me an error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: The specified type member 'Location' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

In case this is true:

```
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Objects/SqlClient/SqlSpatialFunctions.cs
```

How did this work in examples over the web?

UPD. The same problem using Intersects()

```
var center = DbGeography.FromText(string.Format("POINT({0} {1})", latitude, longitude), 4326);
var region = center.Buffer(radius);
var result = db.Entities.Where(x => x.Location.Intersects(region) == true).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're likely to get the same, if not better performance using STIntersects() or STWithin() - or their EF equivalent;

```
// SQL STIntersects() equivalent    
var result = db.Entities.Where(x => x.Intersects(region)).ToArray();

// SQL STWithin() equivalent    
var result = db.Entities.Where(x => x.Intersects(region) == true && x.Difference(region).IsEmpty == true).ToArray();
```

Use 'Intersects' if you want all Locations which are wholly OR partially in the region.  Use 'Within' if you only want those wholly within the region.

Comment: updated post. Intersects() throws the same exception.

Comment: @deeptowncitizen - how odd!  And you're using EF6?  How have you mapped the table?

Comment: Yes, that is EF6. I had a table with Lng, Lat fields. I added Location of type Geography. And mapped this new column on Entity DbGeography. btw SQL requests work well

Answer (score 0):

In case you're using DB First approach it is necessary to update model from Model Browser, but not manually.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my Linq query would not allow me to use:

```
x.Intersects(region) == true
```

I had to change this to

```
x.Intersects(region).IsTrue
```